# How to do fire and forget post request in python

Tags: async-await, python-requests, python-3.6

I am sending a post request in opencv script,the script is waiting for response and delays the execution of remaining block of code.

```
def main():
 do something
 while true:
  opencv block
  r = request.post(url)
```

Comment: can you share you code what you did yet

Comment: You can use Python Twisted (Twisted is an event-driven networking engine written in Python).